# How to use bootstrap modal for update the data?

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal, ejs

I am working on e-commerce app using ejs template and nodejs as backend . In that I have admin role for administrative work . I create Bootstrap modal for update the order status .  But I am able to only update the first order , if I try to any other order only first order gets update . Can anyone please help me to sort out this problem .

**allOrders.ejs (list of orders & modal)**

```js
<%- include("../partials/header") %> <%- include("../partials/navbar") %>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <h3 class="text-center mt-2">All Orders</h3>
  <table class="table table-bordered border-primary mt-4 mb-3">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">ID</th>
        <th scope="col">Order Date</th>
        <th scope="col">Order Updated Date</th>
        <th scope="col">Status</th>
        <th scope="col">Amount</th>
        <th scope="col">Actions</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <% for(let order of allOrders ){ %>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><%= order._id %></td>
        <td><%= order.date %></td>
        <td><%= order.updatedAt %></td>
        <td><%= order.status %></td>
        <td><%= order.amount %></td>
        <td className="bg-secondary">
          <!-- Button trigger modal -->
          <button
            type="button"
            class="btn btn-primary"
            data-bs-toggle="modal"
            data-bs-target="#exampleModal"
          >
            Update
          </button>

          <!-- Modal For Edit Status-->
          <div
            class="modal fade"
            id="exampleModal"
            tabindex="-1"
            aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
            aria-hidden="true"
          >
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog modal-lg">
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">
                    Update Order Status
                  </h5>
                  <button
                    type="button"
                    class="btn-close"
                    data-bs-dismiss="modal"
                    aria-label="Close"
                  ></button>
                </div>
                <form
                  class="m-5"
                  action="/admin/<%= currentUser._id %>/order/<%=order._id%>?_method=PATCH"
                  method="POST"
                  novalidate
                >
                  <div class="mb-3">
                    <label for="orderId" class="form-label">Order ID</label>
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      class="form-control"
                      disabled
                      value="<%= order._id %>"
                    />
                    <label class="form-label">Current Status</label>
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      class="form-control"
                      disabled
                      value="<%= order.status %>"
                    />
                    <div class="mb-4">
                      <label for="updateStatus" class="form-label"
                        >Update Staus
                      </label>
                      <select
                        class="form-select form-control"
                        name="status"
                        value="status"
                      >
                        <option name="Processing" value="Processing">
                          Processing
                        </option>
                        <option name="Prepared" value="Prepared">
                          Prepared
                        </option>
                        <option name="Dispatched" value="Dispatched">
                          Dispatched
                        </option>
                        <option name="Delivered" value="Delivered">
                          Delivered
                        </option>
                      </select>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary save">
                    Save Status
                  </button>
                </form>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button
                    type="button"
                    class="btn btn-secondary"
                    data-bs-dismiss="modal"
                  >
                    Cancle
                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <% } %>
  </table>
</div>
<%- include("../partials/footer") %>
```

**routes for order**

```js
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const { isLoggedIn } = require("../middlewere");
const Order = require("../models/order");

router.get("/admin/:id/allorders", isLoggedIn, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const allOrders = await Order.find({}).sort({ date: -1 });
    res.render("admin/allOrders", { allOrders });
  } catch (error) {
    req.flash("error", "Cannot Find Orders");
    res.render("error");
  }
});

router.patch("/admin/:id/order/:orderId", isLoggedIn, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    await Order.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.orderId, req.body);
    req.flash("success", "Order Updated Successfully");
    res.redirect(`/admin/${req.params.id}/allorders`);
  } catch (error) {
    req.flash("error", "Cannot Update Order");
    res.render("error");
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

I am able to fetch all orders but in modal it always shows first order details . I check code from Devtool (https://codeshare.io/8pyknv) also it showing correct info . But modal not  showing it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem exists inside the for loop. In your loop you have a button with an attribute `data-bs-target="#exampleModal"`. That means all rows in your table will have the same button which triggers the modal with id `exampleModal`. All these button will call the same modal.

Apart from this, each order generates a modal with a specific id exampleModal. So all modals have the same id. That's why you always open the first modal. Each modal must have a unique id

To fix this problem, you should give unique ids to modals, for example

```
    <div
        class="modal fade"
        id="Modal<%= order._id %>"
        tabindex="-1"
        aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
        aria-hidden="true"
    >
```

and each button should call its own modal,

```
         <button
            type="button"
            class="btn btn-primary"
            data-bs-toggle="modal"
            data-bs-target="#Modal<%= order._id %>"
          >
```